# Is Time-based One Time Password patented?

Tags: patent-infringement, prior-art, authentication

[This question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47901/how-does-authys-2fa-work-if-it-doesnt-connect-to-the-server/47902) explains how authenticators like Google Authenticator and Authy are able to generate one-time passwords without connecting to a server.

Are there any patents preventing someone from implementing this in their own app? There is a conspicuous lack of authenticators besides the above two, and that makes me worry.

Additionally, if there are some patents that a basic implementation would be infringing on (such as possibly [this one](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20130014237) from 2014?), how does one go about getting a license on FRAND terms from the patent holders?

Comment: Your "this one"  link is to an application that resulted in an issued patent https://patents.google.com/patent/US8973114B2/en. Scrolling down, you will see dozens of patents it cites and dozens more that later cited it. Looks like a very active field with a lot of IP.

Comment: There are probably many patents to be aware of. FRAND licensing is generally only available for patents that are a part of a standard. Any way, licensing is off topic.